# OIDC Azure AD token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, openid-connect, access-token

I am trying to configure a third party web application to use Azure AD as the OIDC provider. The authentication works fine, however I am looking for some claims and not able to find an ID or Access Token. Here is the flow as I am seeing it

1. Call to the login page of the web application. This gets a 302 redirect to the Microsoft OAuth endpoint as below
2. The URL is https://login.microsoftonline.com/-tenantid-/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=-clientid-&redirect_uri=-encodedCallbackURI-&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile&state=123  *This does a 302 to below URL*
3. Next call is to https://login.microsoftonline.com/-tenantid-/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=-clientid-&redirect_uri=-encodedCallbackURI-&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile&state=123&**sso_nonce=O.eyJ0eXAiOiJK......**&client-request-id=-guid-&mscrid=-guid-  *This returns a 200*
4. Next is the redirect back to the hosted web application indicated in teh callback - https://webApplicationURL/callback?**code=0.AQ4Ayjxg80**......&state=123&session_state=5b7c2e43-9eab-4bb1-9f24-d020f144d30d

At this point, the user has successfully been authenticated. However, I would like to find the ID or Access Token received.

The *sso_nonce*(in #3) is in a JWT format but has no claims.

The *code*(in #4) doesn't have any of the claims either and doesnt really seem to be a JWT token format.

So where is the ID Token or Access Token that I can use to decode and see what claims are getting passed (or not)?

Thanks in advance,

Jake.

Comment: Check this post out: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/getting-an-access-token-in-azure-ad-b2c-620c0790b964

Answer (score 1):

To get **tokens** while calling login page of the web application, you can execute the below ***request*** in browser by including **`response_type`** as **id_token+token**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=da5daf42-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx04a52 //your AppID
&response_type=id_token+token   //Required                    
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms   //your Redirect URL  
&response_mode=fragment                            
&scope=openid+profile+email                           
&state=12345                                          
&nonce=678910
```

Make sure to **enable tokens** for your web application before executing the above request like below:

***Go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Authentication -> Enable tokens -> Save***

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

When I executed the above-mentioned **`request`** in the browser, it asked me to **sign in** like below:

[image]

After successful sign-in, it took me to the redirect URL with **tokens in the address bar** like below:

[image]

When you copy-paste the above in **Notepad** or any, you can find both **`access_token`** and **`id_token`** like this:

[image]

I got the **claims** successfully when I decoded the token like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[OpenID Connect (OIDC)  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc)